# Join within join and count of records using SQL in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I've gotten stumped by this SQL query for my Laravel project, so first I'll describe the relationships.

`cartages` has the following fields: `id`, `date_ending`

`cartage_batches` has the following: `id`, `cartage_id`

`cartage_items` has the following: `id`,`batch_id`,`amount`

What I would like to be able to do is query the `cartage` table to be grouped into year and month pulled from the `date_weekending` field. But also grab the count of `cartage_items` in the `cartage_batches` in each months `cartages`.

I know it would involve a join within a join but I'm not entirely certain how to accomplish that best from within Laravel.

Example Data:

```
Cartage

id   date_ending
1    2019-01-01
2    2019-01-08
3    2019-03-04

Cartage_Batches

id   cartage_id
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    2
5    2

Cartage_Items

id   batch_id   amount
1    1          20.00
2    2          5.00
3    2          15.00
4    4          13.00
```

Expected output

```
2019-01 => ['count' => 4],
2019-03 => ['count' => 0]
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - Alrighty, I've added some on. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks...please also show what the expected output is.  It is still not clear exactly what result you want here.

Comment: So above, the key is the year and month I had mentioned, along with the count of the items that have been related through the batches to the cartages themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a raw MySQL query which should generate the result you want:

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(c.date_ending, '%Y-%m') AS ym,
    COUNT(ci.batch_id) AS count
FROM Cartage c
LEFT JOIN Cartage_Batches cb
    ON cb.cartage_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN Cartage_Items ci
    ON ci.batch_id = cb.id
GROUP BY
    DATE_FORMAT(c.date_ending, '%Y-%m');
```

[image: screen capture of demo]

### Demo

Here is what your Laravel code might look like:

```
$result = DB::table('Cartage c')
    ->leftJoin('Cartage_Batches cb', 'cb.cartage_id', '=', 'c.id')
    ->leftJoin('Cartage_Itmes ci', 'ci.batch_id', '=', 'cb.id')
    ->groupBy(DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(c.date_ending, '%Y-%m')"))
    ->select(DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(c.date_ending, '%Y-%m'), COUNT(ci.batch_id) AS count"))
    ->get();
```